# Text flashing on screen in Python

Tags: python

I'm making my first game, just a simple rock, paper, scissors. I am trying to make it so when you click one of the buttons (those being "Rock", "Paper", and "Scissors") it displays an outcome on the screen of who won, that being either the bot, the player, or if it was a draw. If I click the "Rock" button nothing shows, but every so often the text "Bot Wins" displays on the screen for less than a second before disappearing. How do I fix this so the other outcomes display on screen and stay until another button is pressed? Thank you very much

Below is the code

```py
import pygame
import random
from pygame import mixer #Adds the ability to add music 


#Initialzes the pygame
pygame.init()


#Creates the screen width and length 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 667))


#Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
icon = pygame.image.load("fist.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


#Background
bg = pygame.image.load("bg_paper.jpg")


#Font
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Sans", 50, bold = True)


#Background Sound
mixer.music.load("bg_song.mp3")
mixer.music.play(-1) #Loops the bg music


#Button Class
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width() 
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale))) #Scales up and down the picture
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self.clicked = False

    def draw(self): #Draws button on screen
        action = False
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

        #Get mouse position cords
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        
        #Check mouseover and clicked positions
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True
                
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False #Makes it so you can click repeatedly 
        
        return action


#Button Image
button_img = pygame.image.load("button_img.png").convert_alpha()
           

#Text for buttons
def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))
#Creates Button Instances / Button Positions
rock_button = Button(10, 420, button_img, 0.92) 
paper_button = Button(340, 420, button_img, 0.92)
scissors_button = Button(670, 420, button_img, 0.92)

#Outcomes text
def draw_text2(outcome, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(outcome, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))


#Computer Value / Choices
bot_choices = {
    "0": "Rock",
    "1": "Paper",
    "2": "Scissors"
}



#Game Loop
running = True
while running: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0)) #Background of screen

    #Scores
    draw_text("Score: ", font, (0, 0, 0), 40, 340)
    draw_text("Bot Score: ", font, (0, 0, 0), 500, 340)

    #Outcome
    draw_text("Outcome: ", font, (0, 0, 0), 40, 70)

    if rock_button.draw():
        #If player chooses rock
        def is_rock():
            bot_choices[str(random.randint(0, 2))]
        if bot_choices == "Rock":
            outcome = "Match Draw"
        elif bot_choices == "Scissors":
            outcome = "Player Wins"
        else:
            outcome = "Bot Wins"
        draw_text2(outcome, font, (0, 0, 0),300, 70)    
        print("R")
    draw_text("ROCK", font, (0, 0, 0), 100, 490) #Text for buttons
    if paper_button.draw():
        print("P")
    draw_text("PAPER", font, (0, 0, 0), 420, 490)
    if scissors_button.draw():
        print("S")
    draw_text("SCISSORS", font, (0, 0, 0), 700, 490)
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have looked this problem up but can't find anything on it, though I may just be wording it wrong when I do.

Comment: Without a [mre], it's impossible to tell exactly what might be causing the text to disappear. Unless you want vague guesses, you'll have to be less vague.

Comment: @RandomDavis Fixed it. I just put all the code in there if that helps

Comment: That's not **minimal**. It has code for music and other unnecessary things. I suggest reading the [mre] page for clarification of what **minimal** means in this context.

Comment: There is something funky going on with `def is_rock():`

Comment: @JonSG What is it?

Comment: Why is `is_rock` never called?

Answer (score 1):

If the player chooses "rock" you seem to define a function where I think you want to randomly select a computer move.  Try:

```
    if rock_button.draw():
        #If player chooses rock
        bot_choice = random.choice(list(bot_choices.values()))
        if bot_choice == "Rock":
            outcome = "Match Draw"
        elif bot_choice == "Scissors":
            outcome = "Player Wins"
        else:
            outcome = "Bot Wins"

        draw_text2(outcome, font, (0, 0, 0),300, 70)    
        print("R")
```

Comment: I got this error: line 348, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
           ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try: `bot_choice = random.choice(list(bot_choices.values()))`

Comment: It worked, and I am now seeing all of the outcomes on the screen. Though they are still only flashing on for a brief second and then disappearing. Getting somewhere at least !

Answer (score 0):

draw_text2(outcome, font, (0, 0, 0),300, 70)

put this line after print('R') and unident it, because you are only drawing it in the rock_button.draw()=true condition

```
if rock_button.draw():
    #If player chooses rock
    bot_choice = bot_choices[str(random.randint(0, 2))]
    print(bot_choices)
    if bot_choice == "Rock":
        outcome = "Match Draw"
    elif bot_choice == "Scissors":
        outcome = "Player Wins"
    else:
        outcome = "Bot Wins"  
    print("R")

draw_text2(outcome, font, (0, 0, 0),300, 70)
```

Comment: If I do this, I get the error: name 'outcome' is not defined

Comment: define it in the beginning of your code as ""

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "" ?

Comment: just copy paste the line: `outcome = ""` in the beginning of your code, define outcome as a empty string.        When your code starts, there has not been outcome yet, but since you want to keep displaying it when the game is done, you have to define it as "" in the beginning since there has not been any results yet

Comment: Ah ok, I get what you mean now. I just did that, and I don't get any error message though the outcome still only flashes on screen for less than a second and disappears.
EDIT: I moved the outcome = "" underneath def draw_text2 and it worked !! I have no idea how, but it did. I appreciate your help greatly !